# Adjoint Operator between Banach Spaces is isomorphic iff Operator is

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

If $T: X \to Y$ is an [isometric] isomorphism between normed spaces $X$ and $Y$, then also $T^{\prime}:Y^{\prime} \to X^{\prime}$ is an [isometric] isomorphism. 
If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach Spaces, even the converse holds.

$X^{\prime}$ stands for the dual space of $X$.

I already proved the statement for the non-banach case. For the banach space case (converse direction), im pretty clueless.
Applying the proven statement again to $T^{\prime}$ yields that $ T^{\prime \prime}: X^{\prime \prime} \to Y^{\prime \prime}$ is isomorphic, but thats not quite want i need.

I hope you can help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: if $X$ is a Banach space then there is a natural isometric embedding of $X$ into $X''$.  You can check that the restriction of $T''$ to this subspace recovers $T$.

Comment: The term "isomorphic", as it is typically used, does not mean "is an isomorphism".

Comment: @Nate
So you are saying $T^{\prime \prime}_{| \Phi(X)}$ works as $T$, when $\Phi(X)$ is the Image of the natural embedding you mentioned. I understand that, but why exactly do we need X to be a banach space here?

Comment: For instance, suppose $X$ is a dense subspace of $Y$ and $T$ is the inclusion map.  This is not an isomorphism because it is not surjective, but its adjoint $T'$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, there is a natural isometric embedding $\Phi_X$ from $X$ into $X''$, defined by $(\Phi_X x)(f) = f(x)$ for $f \in X'$, and likewise $\Phi_Y$ from $Y$ into $Y''$.  You can verify that
$$T'' \Phi_X = \Phi_Y T.$$
Now suppose $T'$ is an isomorphism; then by the forward direction of the statement, $T''$ is too.  Then you can check that $T$ is injective and bounded, and that if $T''$ is an isometry then so is $T$.  You can also show that $T$ has dense image, using Hahn-Banach: suppose that $f \in Y'$ satisfies $f(Tx) = 0$ for all $x \in X$, and conclude that $f=0$.

It remains to check that $T$ is surjective and that $T^{-1}$ is bounded.  Here you need the assumption that $X$ is Banach.  In this case you can show that the range of $T'' \Phi_X$ is closed in $Y''$.  In particular it is complete, and so you can show that the range of $T$ is also complete.  Since the range was already dense, this shows that $Y$ is Banach and that $T$ is surjective.  Now the open mapping theorem lets you conclude that $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

Note it isn't necessary to assume that $Y$ is Banach, but it follows from the other assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i was able to understand and follow every step but the fact that T is bounded. Could you please explain that further?
If $T^{\prime \prime}$ is bounded, i agree immediately.
I guess it's rather obvious, but i don't see it yet.

Comment: @ManuelSommer: The adjoint of a bounded operator is bounded.  So if $T'$ is bounded then so is $T''$.  (Presumably you already used or showed this in the first part of your proof?)